# Java void as Runnable with parameter

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, runnable

I have this method:

```
public static void do(Runnable r1, String s1, Runnable r2){}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        do(null, "blabla", this::method); //works
        do(null, "blabla", this::method2(true)); //does not work
    }
    public void method(booolean) {}
    public void method2() {}
}
```

How do I get this to work for a method with a parameter?

Comment: Can you include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You cannot name a method `do`. So it doesn't even compile. So I agree to jrtapsell.

Answer (score 4):

```
do(null, "blabla", () -> method(true));
```

If your first line works - it strange, because `method()` requires a param, but `method2()` - doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Because **Runnable's** run() method does take any parameter that's why **this::method2(true)** does not work.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

As here through **MethodReference** you are providing the implementation of run() method.